# Halcon - ways to filter images

Tags: image, filter, halcon

What are ways supported by halcon to filter a raw image to help extract various kinds of features?

I'm particularly looking for ways to to look at the informations contained in raw images.. not a sum of tons of filters.. Difficult to explain what I mean.. For example: you can look at the R G B channels, you can looks at the HSL/HSV values...

Is there anything more that can be extracted from the raw image? Not looking for things like edge extraction or things like that.. simply different ways to extract data from the original image.

We could define it like this: any filter that in combination with threshold could help to get a selection of a particular object.

**EDIT:**
I try to clarify... This question is not related to a specific Image or situation, its more of a general question. I would like to understand what "primitive" filters can be applied to an image, to help the "threshold" function to do its job. Sort of like you can split it into RGB, or in HSL/HSV, I was wondering if there are other filters that help you in the extraction of certain imageproperties that are good to know.
so the input is any color image, and the output are one or more grayscale channels... beside having the color information, are there ohter filters that give out a grayscale image that can be thresholded?

Comment: I think that this question is not clear. Please, can you give an example of what you'd like to select?

Comment: I tried to explain it a little bit better, but I get that it is difficult to understand my question.. please let me know if it clarifiest a bit..